# $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{H_n}{n^s}$ in terms of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{H_n}{n^s}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

I have been looking for an equation that relates the above sums to no avail. Perhaps, I am missing some important Harmonic identities.

In the sums, $H_n$ represents the $n^{th}$ harmonic number.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: After searching with google, I think equations (3.1) and (3.2) in https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwimmcHM-ODLAhXUBo4KHaY2DkUQFgg-MAQ&url=%68%74%74%70%3a%2f%2f%77%77%77%2e%6d%61%74%68%2e%69%6c%6c%69%6e%6f%69%73%2e%65%64%75%2f%52%45%47%53%2f%72%65%70%6f%72%74%73%31%32%2f%53%63%68%6d%69%64%74%2e%70%64%66&usg=AFQjCNGygK52hqM_IiIBQLz8vBfEegvZxA might be sufficient to deduce the OP's relation.

Comment: I am struggling to find the connection you are speaking of. If you can find the time to elaborate, please do!

Comment: If you are interested in numerical values, I recommend applying an Euler sum.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

First, calculate the ordinary generating function (OGF) of <$H_n$>, which is
$$
H(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n z^n.
$$
Note that each term in  is the convolution of <$a_n$> $=$ < $1,1,1$, $\ldots$ > and the reciprocals $=$<$0,1,1/2,1/3$, $\ldots$>, i.e.,
$$
H_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}.
$$
The OGFs of < $a_n$ > and < $b_n$ > are
$$
A(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{1-z}, 
$$
and
$$
B(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^{n+1}}{n}=-z \ln(1-z)
$$
respectively.
Thus, 
$$
H(z)=A(z)B(z)=\frac{-z \ln(1-z)}{1-z}.
$$
Let $G^{(j)}(z)$ denote the $j$th-order derivative of $G(z)$, and let
$$
{k \brace j}_* = -\frac{1}{j} {k \brace j-1}_* + \frac{1}{j} {k-1 \brace j}_* 
+[k=j=1]_\delta +[k=j=0]_\delta. \tag{1}
$$

By equation (3.2) in [Generating Function Transformations Related to the Form of Dirichlet Series and Applications](https://www.google.lt/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiZpICeqePLAhVqnIMKHZXzBZMQFggaMAA&url=%68%74%74%70%3A%2F%2F%77%77%77%2E%6D%61%74%68%2E%69%6C%6C%69%6E%6F%69%73%2E%65%64%75%2F%52%45%47%53%2F%72%65%70%6F%72%74%73%31%32%2F%53%63%68%6D%69%64%74%2E%70%64%66&usg=AFQjCNGygK52hqM_IiIBQLz8vBfEegvZxA), 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{g_n z^n}{n^k}= \sum_{j=1}^\infty {k+2 \brace j}_* z^j G^{(j)}(z). \tag{2}
$$

The OP's series is
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{H_n}{n^k} = \sum_{j=1}^\infty {k+2 \brace j}_* (-1)^j H^{(j)}(-1),
$$
for $k \in \mathbb N.$

Comment: IMHO, more effort is required to derive the final answer through finding the relation between the OGF and the Dirichlet generating function.

Answer (score 0):

The article "*Generating Function Transformations Related to the Form of Dirichlet Series and Applications*" was a 2012 REGS research article of mine at UIUC. The content in this article (which has apparently been moved online) has been superseded by the more recent work in [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09666) (published in the Online Journal of Analytic Combinatorics in 2017) and [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.00957) (also to appear in OJAC in 2018).

I think that there's another way to express these sums without having to resort to that level of abstraction and taking the limiting cases as $z \mapsto 1$ suggested by the previous post. Namely, we can perform the same trick in finding an exact expression for the *alternating zeta function* $\zeta^{\ast}(s)$ in terms of $\zeta(s)$ using the identity that $H_{2n}-H_n = H^{\prime}_{2n}$ where $H^{\prime}_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}$:
$$\begin{align} 
H_1^{\ast}(s) & := -\frac{H_1}{1^s} + \frac{H_2}{2^s} - \frac{H_3}{3^s} \\ 
     & = -H_1(s) + (1+2^{-s}) \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{H_{2n}}{n^s} \\ 
     & = -\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{H_n}{n^s} + (2^s+1) \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{H_{2n}}{(2n)^s}. 
\end{align}$$
This assumes that you have a known series representation for the second term on the right-hand-side of the previous equation, but I think it's definitely more in the direction you were heading with the question.